# Using Crockford's base 32 for IDs in URLs?

Tags: javascript, url, encoding, base32

I'd like to write some IDs for use in  URLs in [Crockford's base32](http://www.crockford.com/wrmg/base32.html). I'm using the [base32 npm module](https://github.com/agnoster/base32-js).

So, for example, if the user types in http://domain/page/4A2A I'd like it to map to the same underlying ID as http://domain/page/4a2a

This is because I want human-friendly URLs, where the user doesn't have to worry about the difference between upper- and lower-case letters, or between "l" and "1" - they just get the page they expect.

But I'm struggling to implement this, basically because I'm too dim to understand how encoding works. First I tried:

```
var encoded1 = base32.encode('4a2a');
var encoded2 = base32.encode('4A2A');
console.log(encoded1, encoded2);
```

But they map to different underlying IDs:

```
6hgk4r8 6h0k4g8
```

OK, so maybe I need to use decode?

```
var encoded1 = base32.decode('4a2a');
var encoded2 = base32.decode('4A2A');
console.log(encoded1, encoded2);
```

No, that just gives me empty strings:

```
"    "
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get 4A2A and 4A2A to map to the same thing?

Comment: What happens if you try to use decode on `6hgk4r8`? Does that work? Are you sure `4a2a` is a valid base-32 encoding for that library?

Comment: Yes, that does work. I think perhaps you're right and `4a2a` is not a valid base-32 encoding... but why not?

Comment: Well, when I run it here, 4a2a actually returns output, a quotation mark and the control character 0x84. So I'm not sure where you got 4a2a from, but if it was supposed to return text (as opposed to a number), it uses a different base-32.

Answer (score 3):

For an incoming request, you'll want to *decode* the URL fragment. When you create URLs, you will take your identifier and *encode* it. So, given a URL `http://domain/page/`**`dnwnyub46m50`**, you will take that fragment and decode it. Example:

> `#> echo 'dnwnyub46m50'| base32 -d`
>
> `my_id5`

The library you linked to is case-insensitive, so you get the same result this way:

> `echo 'DNWNYUB46M50'| base32 -d`
>
> `my_id5`

When dealing with any encoding scheme (Base-16/32/64), you have two basic operations: `encode`, which works on a raw stream of bits/bytes, and `decode` which takes an encoded set of bytes and returns the original bit/byte stream. The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32) on Base32 encoding is a great resource.

When you decode a string, you get raw bytes: it may be that those bytes are not compatible with `ASCII`, `UTF-8`, or some other encoding which you are trying to work with. This is why your decoded examples look like spaces: the tools you are using do not recognize the resulting bytes as valid characters.

How you go about encoding identifiers depends on how your identifiers are generated. You didn't say how you were generating the underlying identifiers, so I can't make any assumptions about how you should handle the raw bytes that come out of the decoder, nor about the content of the raw bytes being passed into the encoder.

It's also important to mention that the library you linked to is not compatible with Crockford's Base32 encoding. The library excludes `I, L, O, S`, while Crockford's encoding excludes `I, L, O, U`. This would be a problem if you were trying to interoperate with another system that used a different library. If no one besides you will ever need to decode your URL fragments, then interoperability doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The source of your confusion is that a base64 or base32 are methods of representing numbers- whereas you are attempting in your examples to encode or decode text strings.

Encoding and decoding text strings as base32 is done by first converting the string into a large number. In your first examples, where you are encoding "4a2a" and "4A2A", those are strings with two different numeric values, that consequently translate to encoded base32 numbers with two different values, 6hgk4r8 6h0k4g8

when you "decode" 4a2a and 4A2A you say you get empty strings. However this is not true, the strings are not empty, they contain what the decoded number looks like, when interpreted as a string. Which is to say, it looks like nothing because 4a2a produces an unprintable character. It's invisible. What you want is to feed the encoder numbers, not strings.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has

parseInt(num, 32)

and

num.toString(32)

built in in a way that's compatible with Java and across JavaScript versions.